# The live graph stops when the mouse pointer is put inside the graph area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

The live graph stops when the mouse pointer is put inside the graph area. I need to have a live graph that displays values continuously irrespective of mouse movement.Please help me out.

The code is as follows.Please use "  jsfiddle.net  "

HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        var chart;
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'areaspline',
                animation: true, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var seriesa = this.series[0];
                       var seriesb = this.series[1];
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var x1 = (new Date()).getTime(); // current time
                              var  y1 = Math.random();
                            var x2 = (new Date()).getTime();
                            var  y2 = Math.random();

                            seriesa.addPoint([x1, y1], true, true);
                             seriesb.addPoint([x2, y2], true, true);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Time'
                },


               tickWidth: 1 ,
              //  tickWidth: 2,
            type: 'datetime',
            labels:
            {
                enabled:false
            },
            tickColor: '#F00',
            },


            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'speed'
                },


                 labels: {
                formatter: function() 
                {
                    if(this.value < 1000)
                    {
                        return this.value +'kbps';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var thisvalue = this.value;
                        thisvalue = thisvalue/1000;
                        thisvalue = thisvalue.toFixed(1); 
                        return thisvalue +' mbps';
                    }
                },
                style:{
                    color: '#a6a6a6',
                    font: '10px Arial'
                }
            },







                plotLines: [{
                    value: 50,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {//WE need shared tooltip
                formatter: function() {

                var s = '<br>'+ this.x +'</br>';

                $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                    s += '<br/>'+ point.series[i].name +': '+
                        point.y +'<m>';
                });

                return s;
            },

                shared: true

            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },


            series: [{
                name: 'download data',

                color: '#037472',
                lineWidth:2,
                fillOpacity: 1,
                fillColor: 
                {
                    linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 180],
                    stops:
                    [
                        [0, 'rgba(123, 195, 194,1)'],
                        [1, 'rgba(123, 195, 194,0)'],
                    ]
                },



                data: (function() {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -30; i <= 0; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: Math.random()
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                })()
            },
                     //2nd graph plotting
                     {

                     name: 'Upload Speed',
                color: '#068cca',
                lineWidth:2,
                fillOpacity: 1,
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 180],
                    stops:
                    [
                        [0, 'rgba(99, 204, 255,1)'],
                        [1, 'rgba(99, 204, 255,0)']
                    ]
                },
                         data:(function(){
                             // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -30; i <= 0; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: Math.random()*3000
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                })()


                     }


                    ]
        });  //containers end highcharts ends
    });

});
```

Comment: ALSO , use jquery 1.9.1 from the " Framework and Extensions " in the left side upper corner of jsfiddle.net. Thank You

Comment: Why don't you create the fiddle and link to it? Help us to help you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=PspQ1g5Hg6

Comment: This is the public link to the fiddle.I am having issues with browser compatibility , which includes IE 8 , Mozilla Firefox where the graph isn't drawn.Also there is some lag between the graph and the data points that are plotted in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work, because in the tooltip you referr to incorrect object, like point.series[i].name, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I did change the tooltip and its working.But I have issues regarding the compatibility with IE8 and mozilla firefox.